# String formatting and parsing in C

Tags: c, string, hex, string-formatting

I am receiving string in hex form, input string: `"E5A682E682A8"`.
I want to display string from it in C programming.

i.e. here 3 bytes makes one character (Chinese).
I am getting output using below statement:

```
unsigned char output[] = "\xE5\xA6\x82\xE6\x82\xA8";
```

But i need help on getting this format from Input string.
How to parse and process this string to get this output?

Comment: Your question is unclear, please show the raw memory content you're receiving and what output you want.

Comment: You could build a loop around `sscanf` and the `%2x` format.

Comment: @SteveSummit  :D Using a cannon to shoot a sparrow

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is probably with `scanf`.  The `%x` format reads hexadecimal, and you can restrict it to two hexadecimal digits at a time with a width modifier, like `%2x`.  The program would look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    while(scanf("%2x", &c) == 1)
        putchar(c);
}
```

Note that it's important to check `scanf`'s return value, to make sure it actually found the input you were expecting.  This program will stop when it reaches EOF, or when any non-hexadecimal input is encountered.

Incidentally, because of the way `scanf` works, this program will also accept whitespace between the hexadecimal pairs.  So the input could be `"E5 A6 82 E6 82 A8"`, or there could even be multiple lines:

```
E5 A6 82
E6 82 A8
```

In this case, that's probably fine.

Comment: scanf for it. Using a cannon (or Cruise missile) to hunt the sparrow.

Comment: The proper type for an argument to receive the result of a `%2x` conversion is `unsigned int *` rather than `int *`.

Answer (score 0):

Should look something like that:

```
char char_to_hex(char c) {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') return c - '0';
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') return 10 + c - 'A';
        else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') return 10 + c - 'a';
        else error();
}

char* parse(char* str) {
        int len = strlen(str);
        char* output = malloc(len / 2 + 1); // assuming str is in valid format, so len is even
        char* output_ptr = output;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
                char c = char_to_hex(str[i]) * 16 + char_to_hex(str[i+1]); // convert 2 chars to hex
                *output_ptr++ = c;
        }
        *output_ptr = '\0'; // terminate
        return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect 2 characters from the input string and make it into a single byte. That would be your output string.

You can do it using this function.

```
int get_byte(char b) {
    if (b >= 'A' && b <='F')
        return b - 'A' + 10;
    else if (b >= '0' && b <='9') 
        return b - '0';
    return -1;
}


char* output_string(char *src) { // Assumes a nul terminated string    
    int length = strlen(src);
    assert(length % 2 == 0);
    char *output = malloc(length/2 + 1);
    assert(output != NULL);
    char *to_ret = output;
    while(*src) {
        int nibble1 = get_byte(src[0]);
        int nibble2 = get_byte(src[1]);
        assert(nibble1 != -1 && nibble2 != -1);
        *output = (nibble1 << 4) | nibble2;
        output++;
        src+=2;  
    }
    *output = 0;
    return to_ret; 
}
```

Here is a working [demo](https://ideone.com/PqE5tt) for the example.